# react-spring equivalent of react-pose PoseGroup

Tags: reactjs, react-spring, react-pose

React Pose PoseGroup simply animates elements of a list when the list change with the  flipMove option

https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-herschel-37bvs

How to do it with  react-spring?

```
{items.map(item => (
    <Item key={item} />
  ))}
```

I'd like to animate the list if an item is removed, and the animation smoothly fill the gap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animating to position is a little more difficult in react-spring, as you have to manipulate the positions as styles. I like to use hook based animation so I converted the component to function.
The best way to solve this problem is the useTransition function in react-spring. You can define from, enter and leave styles for it. And it will apply to each array item as they removed or added.

For the position I need the y position first as data then as a property. So I map the index as y, and I introduce it to the props as a variable to interpolate from.

```
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState([0, 1, 2, 3]);

  const transitions = useTransition(
    items.map((item, i) => ({ label: item, y: i })),
    item => item.label,
    {
      from: { opacity: 0 },
      leave: { opacity: 0 },
      enter: ({ y }) => ({ y, opacity: 1 }),
      update: ({ y }) => ({ y })
    }
  );
```

Then you can use the transition object in the render part to map the items with styles from it. The trick here is the transform style. The y now change based on the array order. We can create a nice transform style based on it to move the items around.

```
  <ul className="sidepanel">
    {transitions.map(({ item, props, key }, index) => (
      <animated.li
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          opacity: props.opacity,
          transform: props.y.interpolate(
            y => `translate3d(0,${y * 40}px,0)`
          )
        }}
        className="item"
        data-key={item.label % 5}
        key={key}
        onClick={() => {
          setItems([0, 1, 3]);
        }}
      />
    ))}
  </ul>
```

Finally the example, I added an add an shuffle button. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-spring-position-animation-di9rb